# upload file ajax call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am trying to upload and render a csv via an ajax call, but I am receiving this error: "ActionController::UnknownFormat". What I am doing wrong ?

Controller:

```
class HomesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @items = []
  end

  def upload
    myfile = params[:file]
    @items = CSV.read(myfile.path)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

View:

```
<%= form_tag(homes_upload_path, multipart: true, remote: true, :authenticity_token => true) do %>
  <%= file_field_tag :file %>
  <%= submit_tag( "Import" ) %>
<% end %>

<div>
  <div id="items_grid" >
    <%= render partial: 'items_list', locals: {items: @items}  %>
  </div>
</div>
```

upload.js.erb:

```
$("#items_grid").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'items_list', locals: { items: @items } ) %>");
```

Comment: Remote true will not work in case of the image, better use 'remotipart' gem.

Comment: ActionController::UnknownFormat at /homes/upload
ActionController::UnknownFormat @abhsss96

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails remote true does not support in case of attachments. Please use 'remotipart' gem for this functionality.

```
gem 'remotipart', '~> 1.2'

bundle install

//= require jquery.remotipart
```

[Remotipart Gem](https://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart)